# Django Rest Framework: Serialize an Array in a multipart/form-data request

Tags: python, django, http, django-rest-framework, multipartform-data

I am trying to send a List / array using multipart/form-data.

The `ModelSerializer`defines that field using

```python
class RequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  # ...
  in_categories = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True)
```

the `Model` field is defined as

```python
class Request(models.Model):
  # ....
  in_categories = models.ManyToManyField(to='Category',
                                         through='RequestToCategory',
                                           blank=False)
```

now, I got a `ModelViewSet`
defined as follows:

```python
class RequestViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   # ...
   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.data)
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True))
        print(serializer.validated_data)
```

However, the `in_categories` field never gets populated with actual data, nor does the validator `raise` an exception when called.

I did not find any way to transmit the data in a way the field actually gets a list of keys as defined. I tried three things:

1. Sending the data as literal resulting in `request.data = <QueryDict: { ... 'in_categories': ['[2, 3]'] ...`
2. Sending the data as array resulting in `request.data = <QueryDict: { ... 'in_categories[0]': ['2'], in_categories[1]': ['3']  ...`
3. Sending the data as array with extra key resulting in `request.data = <QueryDict: { ... 'in_categories[0]id': ['2'], in_categories[1]id': ['3']  ...`

Each solution (i) arrives at the `ViewSet`, (ii) validates correctly but does (iii) **not** reflect into `serializer.validated_data`.

Do I miss something? I spent already hours on this, finding no solution on how to make DRF understand what I want.

Comment: For anyone still curious: I couldn't fix it; I literally deserialized it on my own by transmitting via '[1,2,3]' and parsing it like someone would do in a programmers educational task ;)

Comment: I feel like doing this right now...

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to send a list is to use `in_categories[0]`, `in_categories[1]`, etc.

When you get the data in the view, it is indeed a bit weird:

```py
<QueryDict: {'in_categories[0]': ['8'], 'in_categories[1]': ['9'], ...}>
```

But as soon as you pass it down to the serializer, it makes sense. For example if you redefine the `create` method of your serializer, the input will look like:

```py
{'in_categories': [8, 9], ...}
```

I wrote a small [article](https://b0uh.github.io/drf-how-to-handle-arrays-and-nested-objects-in-a-multipartform-data-request.html) about this issue if you want more information.

Answer (score -2):

For me

```
Request = json.loads(json.dumps(request.data))
```

has fixed the issue

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).