# How to save multipart / formdata turned into a QueryDict using Django REST Framework (DRF) and ModelSerializer

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, multipart, form-data

I am sending multipart/formdata from a Next.js API and I can format the data whichever way I want but I am struggling to get the right format.

For now, I have the following formdata:

```
<QueryDict: {
    'name': ['Test Product'],
    'brands[0]': ['1'],
    'brands[1]': ['2'],
    'option_types[0]': ['1'],
    'product_variants[0]option_values[0]': ['1'],
    'product_variants[0]option_values[1]': ['2'],
 >
```

and the following ModelSerializer:

```
class ProductDetailAdminSerializer(
    UniqueFieldsMixin, ProductAdminMixin, WritableNestedModelSerializer
):
    categories = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, allow_null=True, queryset=Category.objects.all()
    )
    option_types = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, allow_null=True, queryset=OptionType.objects.all()
    )
    brands = PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, allow_null=True, queryset=Brand.objects.all()
    )
    product_variants = ProductVariantDetailAdminSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (
            "pk",
            "name",
            "subtitle",
            "sku_symbol",
            "categories",
            "brands",
            "description",
            "option_types",
            "product_variants",
        )
```

My ModelSerializer is not accepting the way I am specifying the lists/arrays. For instance, if I try to do:

```
def validate_option_types(self, data):
    print(data)
    return data
```

I get an empty list meaning the format for `option_types` list is wrong and the same applies for the `product_variants` and `option_values`. I am simply passing the QueryDict obtained from `request.data` as follows:

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = ProductDetailAdminSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse(serializer.data)
    return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

The serializer and everything else are working fine if I use a JSON version of the QueryDict above and the JSON content-type. Incidentally, if I use `ListField` instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` it also works as expected although, `ListField` doesn't actually give me the objects required.

So to summarise my question, what is the correct QueryDict format (specifically for fields which represent lists) for the DRF ModelSerializer? Or is there an extra step that I am missing in getting the QueryDict to the format expected by the model serializer.

Comment: Is brand, option_types and product varient many to many field? If yes then this is not the right way.

Comment: Hi @RanuVijay . ```brands``` and ```option_types``` are many to many but ```product_variants``` is many to one.  What would be the correct way to go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` can't process multipart/formdata in the desired way. [Here's a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64500753/django-rest-framework-serialize-an-array-in-a-multipart-form-data-request).

My solution has been to convert all the non-file form data into a single JSON string from the front-end i.e.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('form_data', JSON.stringify(data));
```

and then in Django, in the `create` function of my viewset, do something like

```
data = ujson.loads(request.data.get("form_data"))
new_query_dict = QueryDict('', mutable=True)
new_query_dict.update(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've been sitting on this for a while

Answer (score 0):

ok, You can not add many-to-many type field as the way you are trying to -

first create the object without many to many fields

```
obj = MyModal.save()
```

and then you can do something like -
to create and add your many to many fields.

```
obj.brand.create(name='val1')
obj.option_types.create(name='val2')
```

You can also search StackOverflow on how to add data to ManyToManyFields

Comment: Thanks for the response! Sorry I didn't give enough details in the interest of being conscise. I do create most of my m2m models in completely separate viewsets and serializers because I think it puts less cognitive load on the user but nonetheless, the model creation and saving wasn't what I was struggling with. My challenge was with parsing the POST request content-type.